# Reading from a binary file on 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: c++, c

We are creating a binary file which is used as a checksum . We use the bitset library functions to do this . We have a situation wherein a file created on 32 bit os , is not usable or not readable on 64-bit Os .

```
/***** Code to generate the binary file ******/
#define PB_BITSET_SIZE 32
std::bitset <PB_BITSET_SIZE> m_bitset;
//wstrFileName contains the path to the binary file
FILE *stream = _wfopen (wstrFileName.c_str(), L"wb");

if (!stream) 
    throw std::wstring (L"Opening file failed");

    size_t writeCount = 0;
 // get number of bits set
    size_t bitCount = m_bitset.count();


    // write number of bits set
     writeCount = fwrite(&bitCount, sizeof (size_t), 1, stream);
     if (writeCount != 1) 
     throw std::wstring (L"Writing checksum to file failed");

    // get bitset as unsigend long
     unsigned long bitSetLongValue = m_bitset.to_ulong();

     writeCount = fwrite(&bitSetLongValue, sizeof (unsigned long), 1, stream);

     if (writeCount != 1) 
    throw std::wstring (L"Writing bitset to file failed");

     fclose(stream);
     stream = NULL;


/***************Code to read the binary file ******************/

FILE * stream = NULL;
    size_t bitCount = m_bitset.count();
    unsigned long bitSetLongValue = m_bitset.to_ulong();
    wstring  wstrFileName(L"D:\\Temp\\ECO\\opt.dat");

    stream = _wfopen (wstrFileName.c_str(), L"rb");

        if (!stream) 
            throw std::wstring (L"Opening file failed");

        size_t readCount = 0;

        // read number of bits set


        readCount = fread(&bitCount, sizeof (size_t), 1, stream);

        if (readCount != 1) throw std::wstring (L"Reading checksum from file failed");

        // read bitset as unsigend long


        readCount = fread(&bitSetLongValue, sizeof (unsigned long), 1, stream);
                    if (readCount != 1) *throw std::wstring (L"Reading bitset from file failed");*

        fclose(stream);
        stream = NULL;

        m_bitset = bitSetLongValue;

        // check integrity of file 
        if (m_bitset.count() != bitCount) throw std::wstring (L"Invalid checksum");
```

When we try to read the file on a 64-bit OS , we get the error Reading bitset from file failed

Comment: Your problem is size_t. Never write size_t to a file. It is not portable. Use only `[u]int{8,16,32,64}_t`.

Comment: This looks fine for a 64bit OS. But not for 64bit mode. Please don't confuse those two, they're very different.

Comment: @n.m. I wouldn't say it's just the use of size_t. I would try and avoid sizeof altogether if you want portability.

Comment: @n.m ya..it worked when I used __int64 instead of size_t . I guess the fread is not able to place the filepointer at the appropiate position to read the unsigned long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rely on `sizeof(whatever)` if you are not 100% sure that `whatever` has always the same size - on all platforms, compilers (and their configuration), architectures...

Use types like `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>` for this instead of `size_t` or `unsigned long`.

See comparison of type sizes on different platforms here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: ya..it worked when I used __int64 instead of size_t . I guess the fread is not able to place the filepointer at the appropiate position to read the unsigned long

Answer (score 2):

```
sizeof (unsigned long)
```

Hmm, just from a quick glance this could be an issue, it will be 8 on 64bit machines, and 4 on 32bit machines.

Comment: Both on Win32 32-bit (ILP32) and 64-bit (LLP64) `long` is 32-bits.

Comment: then what could be used ?

Comment: @legends2k Really? I'm a Linux guy. Anyways, you can always write 4 byte values to get around this issue, even on 64bit machines. Instead of using sizeof, just use 4. ( And make sure you use a 4 byte data type ).

Comment: @nemasu if the size of unsigned long is same on 32 and 64 the fread(&bitSetLongValue, sizeof (unsigned long), 1, stream); shouldnt have returned 0